# Jest : ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I try to setup jest for my project following this tutorial : https://dev.to/nedsoft/testing-nodejs-express-api-with-jest-and-supertest-1km6

But when I try to run a basic test I've got the error below :

```
 FAIL  tests/sample.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: describe is not defined

    > 1 | describe('Sample Test', () => {
        | ^
      2 |     it('should test that true === true', () => {
      3 |         expect(true).toBe(true)
      4 |     })

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/sample.test.js:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.521 s
Ran all test suites.
(node:15452) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I try to remove in my package.json :

```
testEnvironment: 'node',
```

But nothing change.

A idea ?

Comment: Have you installed the `jest` package via `npm`?

Comment: @TheLazyChap like that : npm install --save-dev jest supertest

Comment: how are you invoking the test run?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning "npm test" shortcut define in package.json like that : "test": "jest"

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: @Verdouze, doesn't `jest` use `test` instead of `describe`? I just had a quick look at their api docs. eg. `test('some condition', cb)`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning 10.13.0, my problem is solved, i've to downgrade jest version to 25.2.2

Comment: @TheLazyChap I've thing a another way to solve the problem, downgrade the version of jest to 25.2.2, but thanks for help !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok the problem is last version of jest has conflict with node 10.13.0

Source : https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9538

So make this and it is ok :

```
npm install --save-dev jest@25.2.2 supertest
```

Comment: I have the same issue and the downgrade version did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was because I was trying to add a test for one of the pages of my nextjs app.

Instead of adding it inside of the pages folder, I moved the offending test that was causing the `Jest : ReferenceError: describe is not defined` to a `test` folder, and it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

**"jest": "^27.2.0"**. In my case, I got `ReferenceError: describe is not defined` error because I set the [injectGlobals](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/configuration#injectglobals-boolean) configuration to `false` in `jest.config.js`.

The doc about `injectGlobals` configuration:

> Insert Jest's globals (`expect`, `test`, `describe`, `beforeEach` etc.) into the global environment. If you set this to `false`, you should import from `@jest/globals`

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  injectGlobals: true,
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

```js
describe('index', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

After setting `injectGlobals` to `true`, it works fine.

Comment: Can stay with  injectGlobals  as false. Just use a @jest/globals package.